Why is it selecting date from another month that requested one?
I have a table that store time begin and time end of some events. I want to search in this table all even that were occuring during specific day.
Here is example data:



Id
Date begin
Date End
Name




1
2024-04-18 13:30:45
2024-04-18 15:30:45
18-04


2
2024-04-14 13:30:45
2024-04-18 15:30:45
18-04


3
2024-04-15 13:30:45
2024-04-15 15:30:45
15-04


4
2024-04-14 13:30:45
2024-04-14 15:30:45
14-04


5
2024-04-12 13:30:45
2024-04-12 15:30:45
12-04


6
2024-03-18 13:30:45
2024-03-18 15:30:45
18-03


7
2024-03-15 13:30:45
2024-03-16 15:30:45
15-03


8
2024-03-14 13:30:45
2024-03-15 15:30:45
14-03


9
2024-03-12 13:30:45
2024-03-13 15:30:45
12-03



If I want data for the 14/04, this is the excepted output:



Id
Date begin
Date End
Name




2
2024-04-14 13:30:45
2024-04-18 15:30:45
18-04


4
2024-04-14 13:30:45
2024-04-14 15:30:45
14-04



Here is my query:
SELECT * FROM content WHERE
    DATE_FORMAT(dateBegin, '%d/%m/%Y') <= '14/04/2024'
AND
    DATE_FORMAT(dateEnd, '%d/%m/%Y') >= '14/04/2024'

But here is my actual ouput:



Id
Date begin
Date End
Name




2
2024-04-14 13:30:45
2024-04-18 15:30:45
18-04


4
2024-04-14 13:30:45
2024-04-14 15:30:45
14-04


8
2024-03-14 13:30:45
2024-03-15 15:30:45
14-03



Why I get a line from the right day, but of another month ?
I made a Db Fiddle to show this problem.
How can I fix it?
Note: I'm using MariaDB 10.11.4.

Try this:
SELECT * 
FROM content 
WHERE
    dateBegin <= '2024-04-15 00:00:00'
AND
    dateEnd >=  '2024-04-14 00:00:00'

Problem is that you are converting your datetimes to strings. And string comparison behaves... differently.
Is string '14/03/2024' <= '14/04/2024'? Yes.
Is string '15/03/2024' >= '14/04/2024'? Yes.
(Emphasis on the first different character, that determines the order.)
